# set ssh ssh-password on autoinstall

Tags: server, ssh

I have seen, that the ubuntu-server autoinstaller sets a random ssh password and key to be able to connect via installation phase.
But i now want to setup a headless system, so I cannot see the random password.
Is there a way to configure this password or a own public key ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Here is a snippet that can be added to the autoinstall `user-data` file.  It will set the password for the `installer` user and install an authorized_key for the `installer` user.  This config must be added at the root level.  The same level as the `autoinstall:` key, *not* part of the `autoinstall:` section.

```
# set password to r00tme
chpasswd:
    expire: false
    list:
        - installer:$6$.c38i4RIqZeF4RtR$hRu2RFep/.6DziHLnRqGOEImb15JT2i.K/F9ojBkK/79zqY30Ll2/xx6QClQfdelLe.ZjpeVYfE8xBBcyLspa/
ssh_authorized_keys:
    - ssh-rsa FILLINYOUROWNKEYHERE installer
```

#### How it works

When the installer boots, it uses `cloud-init` to configure the installer environment.  The autoinstall `user-data` file is really just a `cloud-init` config used to configure this environment.

In the installer, the [default cloud-init configuration](https://git.launchpad.net/livecd-rootfs/tree/live-build/ubuntu-server/includes.chroot.ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg?id=7a1b5f67dd3ee77167afac2d675e6021808f43d3#n78) will generate an `installer` user by default

```
   default_user:
     name: installer
     lock_passwd: false
     gecos: Ubuntu
     groups: [adm, audio, cdrom, dialout, dip, floppy, lxd, netdev, plugdev, sudo, video]
     sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
     shell: /usr/bin/subiquity-shell
```

and will assign the `installer` user a random password

```
chpasswd:
    expire: false
    list:
        - installer:RANDOM
```

By providing configuration within the autoinstall file, it will override the default config.

Another method would be to provide user info within the autoinstall file.  This will let you more explicitly control the properties of the created user(s).

Comment: Just a clarification about this process. How to obtain `FILLINYOUROWNKEYHERE`? I have to create a key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`? But I'm not the user `installer` on the dev machine...

Comment: @Mark You don't need to be the `installer` user.  Just use the public key created by `ssh-keygen` to fill in the value.  Then any user with access to the corresponding private key will be able to authenticate.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Out of curiosity, what is the meaning of `installer` in this row? `ssh-rsa FILLINYOUROWNKEYHERE **installer**`

Comment: That is the "comment" field.  It does not affect functionality but can be used as an identifier. https://serverfault.com/a/743551/649608

Comment: I am modifying this file, `user-data` in the iso, is that correct?  Where do I find that?  Mounting the iso and using `find . -name "user-data"` comes up with nothing.

Comment: I see this file, `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_ubuntu_autoinstall.py` in the package (`apt-file list cloud-init`), but I'm not finding it in the `iso`.