# Install ubuntu server without screen

Tags: system-installation, headless

Is it possible to install ubuntu server on headless machine?
I downloaded the image on my windows pc, i can flash it to pendrive, but i don't have a screen for the machine i want to install it on.
Can it be done?

The problem was removed.
I wrote removed, not solved, because the solution was to use a screen.

I'm not deleting the thread, because there are couple solutions that might help others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Not really. These instructions are for linux system. As i mentioned, i can prepare whatever is needed on windows machine

Comment: If you're on a windows machine, you can use WSL to run Ubuntu and Linux commands. You will not find instructions here on how to do something on Windows - then you should ask somewhere else - probably [su].

Comment: I'm running vm with ubuntu and trying that solution right now

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you want an interactive install then you will need to use cloud-init to at least configure the password for the `installer` user .  Another option is to automate the install.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1366843/376778

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to preseed ubuntu 20.04 desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233454/how-to-preseed-ubuntu-20-04-desktop)